# customize my google maps icon

Tags: android, google-maps

How can I customize my google maps icon from a dashboard in firebase?
for example in my dashboard I have the ability to create a new category and that category for example food I want to create a perch pin with the icon related to the food to show on the map.!
[My Google Maps icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJffk.jpg)

```
for (int j = 0; j < Mycategories.size() ; j++) {
    String LocalOpen = ArrayGMaps.get(i).getMyOpen();
    String NameCategory1 = ArrayGMaps.get(i).getPlacesCategory();
    String NameCategory2 = 
    Mycategories.get(j).getNameCategory().toLowerCase();

   if (LocalOpen.equals("true") && NameCategory1.equals(NameCategory2)) {
                String setNameIcon = NameCategory2+"green";
                icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.setNameIcon);
                break;
            }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

My Solution

```
 for (int j = 0; j < MycategoriesList2.size() ; j++) {
        String LocalOpen = ArrayGMaps.get(i).getMyOpen();
        String NameCategory1 = ArrayGMaps.get(i).getPlacesCategory();
   if (LocalOpen.equals("true") && NameCategory1.equals(Parametro)) {
       chincheta = MycategoriesList2.get(j).getChincheta_green();
        break;
      } else {
       chincheta = MycategoriesList2.get(j).getChincheta_red();
       break;
      }
   }


 try {
    Bitmap bmImgC = Ion.with(this).load(chincheta).asBitmap().get();

     gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
         .title(ArrayGMaps.get(i).getNamePlaces())
          .snippet(ArrayGMaps.get(i).getDescPlaces())
           .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmImgC))
           .zIndex(2.0f)
           .position(place));
   CameraPosition cameraPosition = new 
   CameraPosition.Builder().target(place).zoom(11).build();
 gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
  } catch (Exception e){
    Log.w("tag","LUAGARES: " + e);
   }
```